# VB6 project issue which applying DAO3.6 library

Tags: vb6

I have an VB6 application.

When trying to Start it prompts an error **ActiveX component can't create object**

The program is failed in below line

```
Set GCIWCon = CreateObject("Dbsecurity.database")
```

I have checked that DAO3.6 library is existed and below line can be executed

```
CreateObject ("Excel.Sheet")
```

Thus, I assumed that DAO3.6 is working properly, but the object "Dbsecurity.database" is not found.

I do have a rough idea about the DAO library but I have no idea **what is missing** in order to make the issued line work.

Can anyone suggest what the object "Dbsecurity.database" can be and how to include it in the VBA?

Thanks

Comment: First, vba and vb6 are different - choose one, please. Second, I don't know what DbSecurity.database is, but I know it's not part of DAO 3.6, or (I believe) part of MS Excel. It's some other third party tool or system, probably. You're receiving the can't create error because you either need to (re-)install or (re-)register whatever DbSecurity.database is or comes from.

Comment: Hi, it should be an VB6 project. So DbSecurity.database is an application or system, where can I find the idenifier? for example, why "Excel.sheet" is refer as Excel? Is there any master table to contain the mapping between idenifiers and the applications? thanks

Comment: There are no Google hits for "DbSecurity.database" so it looks like is a custom class/library, presumably you were to instructed to use it? You need to ask that person for the relevant DLL.

Comment: Here is a possible google search hit (https://livelibrary.osisoft.com/LiveLibrary/content/en/server-v3/GUID-CC0B5188-102D-48D4-A64C-F9886AAC69C7#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-4F3D9C7E-80E3-45A6-A270-BD52EA748A33.xml&docid=GUID-CC0B5188-102D-48D4-A64C-F9886AAC69C7&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CC0B5188-102D-48D4-A64C-F9886AAC69C7). But as @AlexK.recommends, you need to talk with whomever has directed you to use that object identifier about what packages or installs are required.

Comment: _Is there any master table to contain the mapping between idenifiers and the applications?_ That would be the COM definitions stored in the registry (I'm ignoring COM reg-free for this). When you install a package or application, it will write its COM definitions (if any) to the registry - the documentation for that app should then provide you with the information you need to instantiate it (`object.class`) and the methods, properties, events for that interface.